# Is it possible to add multiple on clauses inside an INNER JOIN clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that works perfectly, however I need to change it a bit but it shows me an error and I can't figure out why. Below is the code before and after the changes I made:

**BEFORE:**

```
SELECT *,
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(pho_file_name) FROM post_images WHERE pho_post_id=posts.ID) AS photo_file_array
  FROM users
  INNER JOIN posts ON users.Id = posts.post_author
  ORDER BY posts.ID;
```

**AFTER:**

```
SELECT *,
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(pho_file_name) FROM post_images WHERE pho_post_id=posts.ID) AS photo_file_array
  FROM users WHERE users.Id = "1"
  INNER JOIN posts ON users.Id = posts.post_author ON posts.post_date = "2020-12-04 07:51:21"
  ORDER BY posts.ID;
```

It shows me the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN posts ON users.Id = posts.post_author AND posts.post_date "2020-12...' at line 4
```

I'm a newbie on MySql but from what I can understand I think the error occurs because of the the double ON inside the INNER JOIN. So, is it possible to add multiple `ON` inside the INNER JOIN? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `JOIN` clauses must come before `WHERE` clauses.  Also, if you have more than one `ON` put *ands* between them

Comment: @topsail I tried right now to add the `WHERE` clause between `INNER JOIN` and `ORDER BY` but it still throws the error.

Comment: I agree that these are your two errors. Then you shouldn't use double quotes for string literals, even if MariaDB allows that. Use single quotes for string literals as defined by the SQL standard. Confusing quote types can lead to unexpected results sometimes. And isn't the ID numeric? Why the quotes then? It should be `WHERE users.Id = 1`. And the literal for a timestamp starts with the word timestamp: `AND posts.post_date = TIMESTAMP '2020-12-04 07:51:21'`.

Comment: the query must look like this https://dbfiddle.uk/2j1ttz8e

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Hey, you are right about the double quotes!! Now it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few syntax issues, you can't put `joins` and `where` anywhere, you also need to use the correct *delimiters* and *data types*.

Try the following and note using table and column aliases makes for an easier-to-read query.

Additionally, consider not using `select *` and reference *only* the columns you actually require, if possible.

```
SELECT u.*, p.*, (
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(i.pho_file_name) 
  FROM post_images i 
  WHERE i.pho_post_id = p.ID
) AS photo_file_array
FROM users u
JOIN posts p ON p.post_author = u.Id 
            AND p.post_date = '2020-12-04 07:51:21'
WHERE u.Id = 1
ORDER BY p.ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full working query. The errors (double `ON`clause, `WHERE` clause in the wrong position, wrong quotes) are corrected. Moreover, the ID is compared to an integer now and the post_date to a timestamp literal. I've used table aliases to get this more readable.

```
SELECT
  u.*,
  p.*,
  (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(pi.pho_file_name) 
    FROM post_images pi
    WHERE pi.pho_post_id = p.id
  ) AS photo_file_array
FROM users u
INNER JOIN posts p ON p.post_author = u.id
                  AND p.post_date = TIMESTAMP '2020-12-04 07:51:21'
WHERE u.id = 1
ORDER BY p.id;
```

As to the tables: I suggest you are more consistent with your column names. Why do you call the post ID `post_author`? One would assume a name here. Just call it `post_id` in every table. And you don't have to precede columns with abreviations like `pho`. Just qualify all columns with their tables like I did in my query.